# Orthonormal Sets and Compactness

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

1) Let $\{u_n\}$ $(n=1,2,\ldots)$ be an orthonormal set in Hilbert space $H$. Show that this set is closed and bounded but not compact.

2) Let $Q$ be the set of all $x\in H$ of the form $$x=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty c_n u_n$$ where $|c_n|\leq1/n$. Prove $Q$ is compact.

3) More generally, let $\{\delta_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers, and let $S$ be the set of all $x\in H$ of the form $$x=\sum_1^\infty c_n u_n$$
where $|c_n| \leq \delta_n$. Prove that $S$ is compact iff $$\sum_1^\infty\delta_n^2<\infty$$

4) Prove that $H$ is not locally compact.

I don't really even know where to start with this.

Comment: Do you know what compactness is?

Comment: 1) we have $\|u_n\|=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $\{u_n\}$ is bounded, for compactness we need to proof that $\lim_{\phi(n) \rightarrow\infty} u_n$ don't exist, for that we have $\|u_n\|=1$ so $\|\lim_{\phi(n) \rightarrow\infty} u_n\|=1$, but we can see easily that 
$$
u_n\stackrel{\sigma}{\longrightarrow}0
$$ 
(In fact let $x\in H$ $x=\sum_i c_i u_i $ so $<x,u_n>=\sum_ic_i <u_i,u_n>=c_n\longrightarrow 0$ )
So $\{u_n\}$ isn't compact.

Comment: Thanks. I get part 1 and I think I am on the right track with part 2) now. Any input or proof for parts 3 and 4 are appreciated.

Comment: For #1, boundedness follows from the fact that any two of these points are at a distance of $\sqrt 2$ from each other.  Put an open ball of radius $1/10$ about each point and see that such a ball contains no other point of the set; conclude that they are all isolated; hence the set is closed.  Then observe that those same open balls form an open cover with no finite subcover; conclude that the set is not compact.

Comment: @Hamza : Standard notation is $\langle x,u_n\rangle$, not $<x,u_n>$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Boundedness of $\{u_n\}$ is straightforward.

To show it is closed, show the complement is open (expand $\{u_n\}$ to a basis, fix $x\not\in \{u_n\}$, write $x$ in terms of your basis, note the coefficients of $x$ in this basis must decay, then show $\|x - u_n\| \geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ independent of $n$).

Let $B_{1/2}(u_n) = \{u \in H : \|u - u_n\| < 1/2\}$. Then $\bigcup_n B_{1/2}(u_n) $ is an open cover of $\{u_n\}$. Is there any finite subcover (hint: compute $\|u_n - u_m\|$ for $n\neq m$ using orthogonality)?

Comment: Ah. $||u_n-u_m||^2=(u_n,u_n) + (u_m,u_m)-2Re(u_n,u_m)=2$ so this implies no subcover, no?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts on part 4)?

Comment: The set $\{ u_n \}$ is a closed subset of the closed unit ball. If the closed unit ball is compact, then...

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @BaronVT : The closed unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is NOT compact, as one can see by proving this particular closed subset of it is not compact. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, yes, that is precisely the conclusion I am trying to lead OP toward, by suggesting they calculate $\|u_n - u_m\|$ (showing the balls $B_{1/2}(u_n)$ are mutually disjoint, thus no finite subcover exists).

Comment: @BaronVT : But he didn't ask how to show the ball is not compact.  He asked how to show $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not compact. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The distance between any two of these basis elements is $\|u_i - u_j\|=\sqrt 2$.  Consequently if you put an open ball of radius $<\sqrt 2/2$ around each of them, those balls are pairwise disjoint.  That means any sequence of these points other than $u_i$ must stay out of that ball centered at $u_i$; hence $u_i$ is not a limit point of the set.  Since no point of the set is a limit point of the set, the set is closed.

Hence it is closed and bounded.

But the same set of open balls described above is an open cover with no finite subcover.  (Indeed, it has no proper subcover at all: if you omit even one of those open balls, the remaining ones fail to cover the set.)  Therefore the set is not compact.

If $H$ were locally compact, then every open set would have compact closure.  That would imply every closed ball is compact.  Notice that the argument above shows the closed ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$ cannot be compact because it has a closed subset that is not compact.  Now observe that every closed ball is homeomorphic to that one.  Hence $H$ is not locally compact.